# PHP Convert empty attribute to text or number

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file with attributes

XML Document

```
<SET name="John" lastname="Steve" city="New York" Country=""/>
```

This is converted to CSV file with 4 colums.

CSV File

```
Name,LastName,City,Country
John,Steve,New York,
```

I want to get the Empty content from Country and convert to a default text like USA

I will use str_replace to do this replacement.

The problem is that i don't know how to get the Empty attribute, like if is empy var_dump.

Thanks

Conversion file.

```
$filexml = 'file.xml';
    if (file_exists($filexml)){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$file = fopen('clients.csv', 'w');
        $header = array('Name', 'LastName', 'City', 'Country');
fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');
foreach ($xml->SET as $set){
$item = array();
            $value1 = $set->attributes()->name;
            $value2 = $set->attributes()->lastname;
            $value3 = $set->attributes()->city;
            $value4 = $set->attributes()->Country;

$search_country= array('','10','12')
$replace_country = array('USA','Argentina','Canada')
$item[] = $value1;
$item[] = $value2;
$item[] = $value3;
$item[] = str_replace($search_country, $replace_country, $value4);

fputcsv($file, $item, ',', '"');    
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code you are using for the conversion

Comment: you will have to provide more information on how you are parsing the xml file for its elements and attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `empty` to check if the values are empty

```
$value4 = empty($set->attributes()->Country) ? "USA" : $set->attributes()->Country;
```

Comment: Hi Baba, this is getting: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error):

Comment: My Fault, sorry, this work like charm i forgot one ) Thanks Baba